# How to change the language on validator

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I have Outlook Office on my computer and I added the language package Dutch to my computer.
After that I ran into a lot of failed tests in my C# visual studio project.
I work with Fluentvalidation. When I push my code to develop I don't get errors in my test. So I'm pretty sure the problem is not in my code but on my computer.

So I uninstalled the language package and still got the error.

One of my errors is :

**Not found: UnitKeyName: MaximumLengthValidator - The length of 'Unit Key Name' must be 256 characters or fewer. You entered 400 characters.
In value:  An error occurred when validation the message :
 UnitKeyName: MaximumLengthValidator - De lengte van 'Unit Key Name' moet kleiner zijn dan of gelijk aan 256 tekens. U hebt 400 -tekens ingevoerd.**

Meaning : The validation is in the wrong language , but my collegues don't have this error when I push it to a GIT branch.

Keyboard : English (changed back) --> It was English (tests : works) switch to Dutch (tests fails) --> switched back to English (tests : fails)

Comment: What is the code to get that error?

Comment: Did you try setting the default language in your projects?

Comment: Yes, all is in English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

This did it //

Answer (score 1):

You can change current Thread culture and UI culture.

```
     CultureInfo newCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;
     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
```

Comment: Where do I set this ?

Comment: The problem is when I Change code, the whole solution will change, that's not a thing I wanna do

Comment: In Application_Start or Main, mostly at any entry point.
It is depends on type of your application.